# Map layout by leafletjs

Tags: javascript, php, html, leaflet

I would like display a map on my web-page... For this, I have the following code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<!-- HEAD -->
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Petites annonces</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <style>
        <link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet">
        #title { text-align: center; }
        #mapid { margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; height: 180px; }
    </style>
</head>
<!-- BODY -->
<body>
    <h1 id="title">Petites annonces</h1>

    <div id="mapid"></div>
    <!-- JAVASCRIPT -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([46.62, 2.39], 4);
        L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
            maxZoom: 18,
            attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
                '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
                'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
            id: 'mapbox.streets'
        }).addTo(mymap);
    </script>
</body>
```

But this is the result :

[image: Web page rendering]

Something is missing in my code ?
I don't understand what is the problem... And I have any solution.

So, If you may help me, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the `<link>` element out of your `<style>`.

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
    #title { text-align: center; }
    #mapid { margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; height: 180px; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

`<link>` tag inside the `<style>` was causing the problem. Moving it outside of it solved the problem

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<!-- HEAD -->
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Petites annonces</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>

        #title { text-align: center; }
        #mapid { margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; height: 180px; }
    </style>
</head>
<!-- BODY -->
<body>
    <h1 id="title">Petites annonces</h1>

    <div id="mapid"></div>
    <!-- JAVASCRIPT -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([46.62, 2.39], 4);
        L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
            maxZoom: 18,
            attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
                '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
                'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
            id: 'mapbox.streets'
        }).addTo(mymap);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```